# How to collect and report Timedout in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

```
1. Request 1 
2. Extract some value from Response
3. Verify Assertion
4. LogResults
```

My Request is getting timeodut.. Eventhough it is timedout it is logging error on the step 2  -> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The JSON input text should neither be null nor empty.

But I wanted to specifically log Result as Request Timedout.. How to get that request is timedout or Not?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an assertion to the request step itself.  There is an SLA type assertion which you can say how long the request should result in.  This will be called before the assertion in step 2 in your flow.

Comment: ChanGan, have you tried this solution as suggested by @Chris?